# Uploading file to google drive Rest API V3 from DocumentFile

Tags: android, rest, google-drive-api

I have used SAF to create a file, And I want to upload it to google drive.
All Google drive support is

```
File file = mDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                                .setFields("id, parents")
                                .execute();
```

Where fileMetadata id a java.io.File
But I have a Uri of the created file.
Specifically -

```
pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(mContext, uri);
DocumentFile docImageFile = pickedDir.createFile("image/jpeg", prepend + ".jpg");
```

I have tried diffrent getPath utils - nothing helped.

This is the relevant google API V3 Rest api example code

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder

Comment: Please tell which line(s) in the google example is/are problematic. Do you get an id?

Comment: See if there is a `FileContent` constructor that takes an `InputStream`, or perhaps a `Uri`. If there is, use it. If `FileContent` is limited to files on the filesystem, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, copy that content to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), and then use that file with `FileContent`.

Comment: Dear CommonWare : Extremely painful - I will have to find other solution for uploading videos but it works for images "java.io.File tempfile = new java.io.File(mContext.getExternalCacheDir(), fileNameTemp);
tmpfile.createNewFile();
fileMetadataUri.setName(fileNameTemp);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempfile);
InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(shortFileNameUri));
FileUtil.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();" Thanks, I think that you can write it as an answer

Comment: blackapps - "java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");" it cannot create the file from the uri , I will go with the temp file  thanks.